# Unable to specify dynamic time range in sql query for jdbc river in elasticsearch

Tags: jdbc, lucene, elasticsearch

I am using the jdbc river for elasticsearch to index mysql table data.

My River:

```
 curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/river_mention_reports/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ESTest1_development",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "password",
        "sql" : "select * from table where creation_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)",
        "poll" : "2m",
        "versioning" : false
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "monitoring",
        "type" : "mention_reports"
    }
}'
```

SQL query that I have specified in the river is:

`select * from table where creation_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)`

Now the problem is, the river after every poll removes the data that was indexed outside the time range(current minus 2 minutes) specified in the query, instead of adding fresh data to the index. The reason I have specified a time range is because I don't want the river to reindex the entire dataset again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **"digesting": false** (it defaults true) in the "jdbc" section of your river configuration, where you have "versioning": false now.  BTW, "versioning" defaults to false anyway and actually should be in the "index" section, not the "jdbc" section.